# React Native pass variable to nested component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, nested, gesture

I have a camera and zoom component, they are separate as changing the state in the camera causes it to keep reloading. The issue I have is that I cannot figure out how to get the zoom variable to pass to the camera component so it can effect the zoom.

Here is the camera rendered component (the cameracontainer is an instance of expo camera):

```
return (
        <PinchGesture>
            <CameraBackground>
                <SnapButtonContainer onPress={snap}>
                    <SnapButton  />
                </SnapButtonContainer>
                <CameraContainer
                    ref={(camera) => (cameraRef.current = camera)}
                    type={Camera.Constants.Type.back}
                    //zoom={zoom} < this is where I need to put the variable
                />
            </CameraBackground>
        </PinchGesture>
    );
```

His is the PinchGesture component wrapping the camera:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Animated, View } from "react-native";
import { PinchGestureHandler, State } from "react-native-gesture-handler";

export const PinchGesture = (props) => {

    const [zoom, setZoom] = useState(0);
    const [scale, setScale] = useState(0);
    
    const onPinchHandlerStateChange = (event) => {
        if (event.nativeEvent.oldState === State.ACTIVE) {
            if (event.nativeEvent.scale > scale && zoom <= 1) {
                setZoom(zoom + 0.1);
            } else if (event.nativeEvent.scale < scale && zoom >= 0) {
                setZoom(zoom - 0.1);
            }
            setScale(event.nativeEvent.scale);
        }
        
        console.log('zoom:', zoom);
    };

    return (
        <PinchGestureHandler
                //onGestureEvent={onPinchEvent}
                onHandlerStateChange={onPinchHandlerStateChange}
                zoom={zoom} < this was an attempt to pass the variable
            >
            {props.children}
        </PinchGestureHandler>
    );
}
```

I have tried many different ways to get this to work, the last was using a context, however the pinch gesture would not register the gestures for some reason. Hoping someone knows how I can get this data to the nested component

Comment: Can you put the CameraContainer component or are you importing it directly from expo-camera?

Comment: The complete "camera rendered component" would help too, since you're probably doing something wrong there if the camera reloads

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest have zoom state in the component where you have used PinchGesture and CameraContainer so you can pass function onUpdateZoom as prop in the PinchGesture and on change zoom call this prop function from the PinchGesture to update state in parent component and pass zoom state in CameraContainer.

```
const [zoom, setZoom] = useState(0);

return (
    <PinchGesture
       zoom={zoom}
       onUpdateZoom={(value) => setZoom(value)}
    >
        <CameraBackground>
            <SnapButtonContainer onPress={snap}>
                <SnapButton  />
            </SnapButtonContainer>
            <CameraContainer
                ref={(camera) => (cameraRef.current = camera)}
                type={Camera.Constants.Type.back}
                zoom={zoom}
            />
        </CameraBackground>
    </PinchGesture>
);
```

Below PinchGesture component

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Animated, View } from "react-native";
import { PinchGestureHandler, State } from "react-native-gesture-handler";

export const PinchGesture = (props) => {
    const [scale, setScale] = useState(0);

    const { zoom, onUpdateZoom } = props;
    
    const onPinchHandlerStateChange = (event) => {
        if (event.nativeEvent.oldState === State.ACTIVE) {
            if (event.nativeEvent.scale > scale && zoom <= 1) {
                onUpdateZoom(zoom + 0.1);
            } else if (event.nativeEvent.scale < scale && zoom >= 0) {
                onUpdateZoom(zoom - 0.1);
            }
            setScale(event.nativeEvent.scale);
        }
        
        console.log('zoom:', zoom);
    };

    return (
        <PinchGestureHandler
                //onGestureEvent={onPinchEvent}
                onHandlerStateChange={onPinchHandlerStateChange}
                zoom={zoom} < this was an attempt to pass the variable
            >
            {props.children}
        </PinchGestureHandler>
    );
}
```

Comment: This will not work, as explained in my first line changing state in this component causes the camera to reload and makes the app very slow.

Comment: @Paul Ok then i will suggest use the hook useReducer which you can share state between components https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I have looked at and attempted to implement the reducer solution, however it is problematic due to the need to pass then event to the reducer. In this case its the pinch event, which does not appear to be able to be handled by the reducer.